# Can a person that doesn't have access to a page, view an unpublished article to review?

Tags: users

Can a person that doesn't have access to the backend of my website view an unpublished page?

I.e I want to set up an article but need someone to review before I can publish it. I can't give this person access to drupal, just want them to review the page and content to approve. Is this possible without them logging in?

Comment: You need to clarify your question, on the title it says `access to a page` in the body it says `access to the back end` those are 2 different things. Will this person/anonymous user be able to view the article once it has been published?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want them to login? You can always create a new role that doesn't have all the permissions/powers of an administrator, and let them log in to do their thing.

Comment: I agree with @NoSssweat. How else will you know the correct person reviewed the article. The alternative is to provide a one time login link or to use some emailing system. Have a look at [Guest Pass](https://www.drupal.org/project/guestpass)